# How to skip showing results in HIVE Command Line?

Tags: t-sql, hadoop, hive, ssms, beeswax

I have executed a query in `HIVE CLI` that should generate around `11.000.000` rows, I know the result because I have executed the query in the `MS SQL Server Management Studio` too.

The problem is that in `HIVE CLI` the rows are showing on an on ( right know there are more than `12` hours since I started the execution ) and all I want to know is the time processing, which is showed only after showing the results.

So I have 2 questions :

1. How to skip showing rows results in `HIVE` command line ?
2. If I will execute the query in `Beeswax`, how do I see statistics like execution time , similar with `SET STATISTICS TIME ON` in `T-SQL` ?

Answer (score -1):

You can check it using link given in log .But it wont give you total processing left.